Is it possible to call an Apex method from a custom toast message hyperlink
I have a requirement to implement the undo functionality that is part of the toast message that shows up when a record is deleted using a custom toast message. I know that we are able to use the url element of the messageData parameter to show any link which can be clicked from the custom toast. I want to call my Apex class that undos the delete operation. How would I be able to call this Apex class from a custom toast?
